# jQuery FancyBox: How do I increase the width of the element #fancybox-wrap by 10 px?

Tags: jquery, width, fancybox

In jQuery FancyBox, I need to increase the width of the element #fancybox-wrap by 10 px. What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show some of the relevant code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are in jQuery 1.4

you could

```
$(document).ready() {
    $("#fancybox-wrap").width(function(i,width){
        return width + 10;
    });
});
```